# What "otherwise " means in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

It can be helpful to read your own essay aloud to hear how it sounds, and it can sometimes be even more beneficial to hear someone else read it.  Either reading will help you to hear things that you **otherwise** might not notice when editing silently.  If you feel uncomfortable having someone read to you, however, or if you simply don’t have someone you can ask to do it,you can have your computer read your essay to you.

1. How the word **'otherwise'** can be restated?
   In this context,  [otherwise= if you do not read aloud or had someone else read] ,right?

Confusing matter to me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Otherwise can be changed to alternatively, and means that if you did not read the essay out loud, and it in this sentience is reading the essay for mistakes.

Comment: no problem, im glad i could help.